# css file doesn't apply on html(.jsp file)

Tags: css, jsp

i have a probleme with my css in jsp project 
the probleme is that the css doesn't apply on page 
i've tried to change the path of css files but it doesn't work 
i've also to change 

by : <%@include file="../assets2/css/bulma.css" %> but it Caused more errors related to jsp compilation ...
on network tap (inspect elements) :
[network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxOhv.png)[my project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBNP8.png)
the code on my .jsp file :

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
        <%@ page import="entities.Dossier" %>
        <%@ page import="entities.Responsable" %>
        <%@ page import="entities.Tache" %> 
    <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="web.TrackingServlet"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>tAccueil</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Premium Bootstrap 4 Landing Page Template" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="bootstrap 4, premium, marketing, multipurpose" />
    <meta content="Themesdesign" name="author" />
    <!-- favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

    <!-- google font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Slider-->
    <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="css3/owl.carousel.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="css3/owl.theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="css3/owl.transitions.css" />

    <!-- Magnific-popup -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css3/magnific-popup.css">

    <!-- css -->
    <link href="css3/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css3/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css3/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

    <!--Navbar Start-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-custom sticky sticky-light" id="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- LOGO -->
            <a href="http://localhost:8080/Tracking/Acceuil" class="logo-sticky">
                <img src="img/logogo.png" alt="" class="logo-dark" height="32" />
                <img src="img/logogo.png" alt="" class="logo-light" height="32" />
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="remixicon-menu-fill"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto navbar-center" id="mySidenav">
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                     <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a href="http://localhost:8080/Tracking/Acceuil" class="nav-link">Startseite</a>
                    </li>
                    <c:if test="${session == null }">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="http://localhost:8080/Tracking/loginClient" class="nav-link">Anmelden</a>
                        </li>
                        </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${session != null }">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="http://localhost:8080/Tracking/acceuilClient" class="nav-link">Mein Raum</a>
                        </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="http://localhost:8080/Tracking/deconnexion" class="nav-link">Abmelden</a>
                        </li>
                        </c:if>
                     
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Navbar End -->

    <!-- HERO START -->
    <section class="hero-4-bg position-relative bg-gradient" id="home">
   
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center hero-4-content">
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <h1 class="text-white hero-4-title font-weight-medium mb-4 line-height-1_4">Verfolgen Sie Ihre Datei</h1>
                    <p class="text-white-50 mb-5">WEBTRACK bietet den schnellsten und genauesten Verfolgungsdienst auf der Grundlage einer intelligenten Datenanalyse..</p>
                    <div class="text-center subcribe-form mt-4">
                            <form action="progression" method="post">
                            <c:if test="${id_doc != null }">
                                <input type="text" value="${id_doc }" name="tracking">
                            </c:if>
                             <c:if test="${id_doc == null }">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Geben Sie die Tracking-Nummer ein..." name="tracking">
                            </c:if>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn rounded-pill btn-purple">Verfolgen </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-1">
                   <div class="hero-4-img mt-5 mt-lg-0">
                        <img src="images/hero-4-img.png" alt="" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block">
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="home-bottom-shape">
                    <img src="images/home-4-bottom-shape.png" alt="" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- HERO END -->



    
    <!-- FOOTER END -->

    <!-- javascript -->
    <script src="js2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js2/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js2/scrollspy.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js2/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <!-- COUNTER -->
    <script src="js2/counter.int.js"></script>
    <!-- carousel -->
    <script src="js2/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Magnific Popup -->
    <script src="js2/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js2//magnificpopup-int.js"></script>
    <!-- Main Js -->
    <script src="js2/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to include a .css file to jsp. try this

```
<jsp:include page="../css3/index.css"/>
```

or

```
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/include/header.jsp"%>
```

Comment: i have lot of css files so it caused a memory error org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Impossible de compiler la classe pour la JSP'